# Remove offset from datetimeoffset

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a datetimeoffset 3/18/2019 11:46:10 AM -04:00
I need to convert it to 3/18/2019 11:46:10 AM I don't need to apply the offset.
For lack of better words I just need the last 7 characters removed.

Comment: Cast(yourDateTimeOffsetColumn as datetime)

Answer (score 9):

Convert it to a `datetime2(0)`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),YourDatetimeOffsetColumn) AS Datetime2Column
FROM...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3af4f43bf51852bc37654f25dbc8cb6c)

Comment: Note that converting using an explicit `(0)` is going to remove any potential precision that is stored in the backend. It's the conversion from `DATETIMEOFFSET` to `DATETIME2` that removes the timezone.

Comment: This results in an out-of-range value

Comment: Then your source data isn't a `datetimeoffset`, @MaxTaylor-Hayden . That error can never happen when converting from a `datetimeoffset` to a `datetime2`.

Comment: Most likely, @MaxTaylor-Hayden , you are storing date and time value in a `varchar`; something that is always a bad design choice.

Answer (score 1):

For mssql:

SELECT CAST(Your_Column AS DATETIME) FROM Your_Table

Comment: But this question is tagged for Microsoft SQL Server, so this doesn't answer the problem asked.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, mssql is Microsoft SQL Server. I recently had the same issue and that solved it for me